# Prove or disprove n 〖log〗_10 n ∈θ(n 〖log〗_2 n)

Tags: big-o

I am literally stuck here. I have tried finding the upper and lower bounds but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea to bear in mind is this identity:

```
(log_a x)(log_2 a) = (log_2 x)
```

Why? Because

```
(log_a x)(log_2 a) = log_2 a^(log_a x)        ; t(log_2 a) = log_2 a^t
                   = log_2 x                  ; a^(log_a x) = x by definition
```

For `a=10` and `x=n` we get:

```
(log_10 n) = (log_2 n)/(log_2 10)
```

multiply by `n`:

```
n(log_10 n) = n(log_2 n)/(log_2 10)
```

and get

```
n(log_10 n) = θ(n(log_2 n))
```

since `log_2 10` is a constant.

Comment: We can also notice than θ⋅n⋅log₂(n) equals n⋅θ⋅log₂(n), so we can simply get rid of the leading _n_. We end up with log₁₀(n) = θ⋅log₂(n), which tells that we can turn any logarithm (from a given base) into another one (from another base), just by adding the correct coefficient (which actually is 1/log(targetbase) ).

Answer (score 0):

Go back a step and look at how the log base affects the complexity.
If you can show that the complexity of log10 is the same as log2 you'll be on the right track